# Can we merge tags investing and investment?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tags [investing](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/investing) and [investments](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/investments) have a lot of overlap between them. The average person asking will probably not draw a distinction between them.

Note that [investments](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/investments) already has a synonym in [investment](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/investment).

Answer (score 3):

This is of course too late because the merge was done. But were they truly the same?

**Investing** could have had to do with how to invest
**Investments** could have had to do with what to invest

But we now will never know.

I would caution doing a change of tags after a few hours and an handful of views. And zero votes.

Comment: I guess you'll have to take my word for it when I say that though there's a clear distinction between the verb and noun, they were used interchangeably. I examined dozens of each and saw that many users weren't drawing a distinction between them. However, I did put the discussion tag up, so I don't think I deserve your downvote. But you can disagree if you want. If you want to get right down to it, investments are certainly included in the topic of investing. If we want to remove the synonyms we can, and the work of examining the usage of the tags that needed to be done can still be done.

Comment: but since the merge was done there is no way to know if it was a good idea. there should be a longer time between suggesting a change and it being done.

Comment: Before we started [tag:investing] had ~1200 uses, and [tag:investments] had ~400 uses. There probably were a few users making a distinction between the tags, but the majority likely picked the first tag that came up when they started typing.

Comment: with 1600 questions impacted my vote would have been to make zero global changes.

Comment: With or without the global change, we had 1600 questions with inconsistent usage of the tags across them. As I looked at the option of examining each for cleanup, as well as ongoing maintenance of the separate tags, I figured it was much easier to combine them. I still don't agree that this is harmful to the site in any way.

Comment: In between the time I answered and time I flipper (10 hours) I looked at 40 questions, and found that members used tags at random, the verb and noun were used interchangeably. In the future, I promise to leave more time, a few days, if that's what you think suffices.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Do you (and other members) have a preference which one stays? My inclination, as you can see, was to keep "Investing" but there are more question tagged "Investments".

Noun or Verb?

Comment: I prefer investing as well, with investment and investments as synonyms

Comment: The merge is done.

Comment: There were many more questions tagged 'investing' (>1000). The number 324 above wasn't the overall count of the 'investing' tag but only the cases where the surviving tag would replace the non-surviving one. That there were 324 and not 399 is probably because 75 of the 399 already had tag 'investing' (i.e. at the same time as tag 'investment').

Comment: Thanks Chris. Had I waited (as I agree I should have done) would you be in the camp agreeing to the merger?

Comment: I agree with the tag merger as executed. My nitpick about the numbers was just me being pedantic and correcting your mistaken assertion that tag `investments` had some kind of numbers advantage over `investing`. As for the wait, I'd have been in favour of a wait ... as long as the outcome didn't change ;) Heh.